# In PyTorch, whey does not nn.Dropout perform dropout during training and numerical scale during inference?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

In PyTorch, here is how [`nn.Dropout`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Dropout.html)  works

- training: randomly zeros out some elements, and then scale the output with $1-p$, where $p$ is the probability of dropout
- inference: do nothing
  The scale operation is to ensure roughly the same numerical range between the tensors in training and inference.
  Motivated by this, here's an alternative implementation:
- training: randomly zeros out some elements
- inference: do not zeros out any elements, only scale the output with $1-p$

I am wondering why PyTorch uses the first instead of the second implementation. Is there any potential advantage of the first over the second?

I haven't compare the performances of the two implementations. However, they seems to lead to similar performances.

Any insights will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: dropout is a form of regularization. If just scaling was done during training, that wouldn't be a form of regularization. But during inference, using all of the nodes is meant to provide better inference, by using all of the network. I don't know if there's research showing whether it actually does. The scaling is necessary so that each node still receives inputs of roughly the same size they did during training.  I do know there's a paper that showed using dropout during inference could be used to provide a sort of confidence interval for the prediction.

Comment: Thanks, @Joe. This "regularization" explanation does make sense.

Comment: You're welcome. I found some answers to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44223585/6394617).